# Calculating assets-to-equity from equity-to-assets

Tags: accounting

I've read that to calculate **equity**-to-**assets** using **assets**-to-**equity** the following can be done:

assets-to-equity = 40%

equity-to-assets = 1/0.4 = 2.5

Why does that work out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the formulae are the inverse of each other, and the way to compute the inverse of `X` is `1/X`.  That's just the mathematical definition of "inverse".